# SHA1 in painless (elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

How I can update SHA1 for a lot of millions records in index?

like...

`{
  "query": ...
  "script": "ctx._source.sha1 = sha1(ctx._source.field)"
}`

Painless has not built-in SHA1 function as is as groovy.
Do exist a way without using client-side?
If I can't do this, how I can use python for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Groovy`, `JavaScript`, and `Python` scripting languages were deprecated in `elasticsearch` 5.0 and have been removed from 6.0 ([see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking_60_scripting_changes.html#_groovy_javascript_and_python_languages_removed)). You must use `painless`.

[Here](https://github.com/sektorcap/sha-painless) you can find my sha1 and sha256 painless implementations.